# Strange casting behavior

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I have an array of `int *arr[3];` and its elements are initialized like this :

```
sides[0] = &a;
sides[1] = &b;
sides[2] = &c;
```

Where a=b=5 and c=10. Now when i try to cast the type of the value (from int to double) of the contents of the memory address that each pointer is pointing at, the 3rd value shows up always as 0. Do you know why?

Here's what i'm doing:

```
double a,b,c;
a = (double) *sides[0];
b = (double) *sides[1];
c = (double) *sides[2];
printf("%lf %lf %lf",a,b,c);
```

The `output` i get is:

```
5.0000 5.0000 0.0000
```

Here's the full code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void populateSides(int *[3]);
void calculateTriangleType(int *[3]);

/*
* Function populateSides: Has 1 arg
* 1st arg: an array of int *.
* This function stores the 3 sides of a triangle 
* given by the user into the sides array.
*/
void populateSides(int *sides[]) {
    int i,a,b,c;
    scanf(" %d",&a);
    scanf(" %d",&b);
    scanf(" %d",&c);
    while((c <= b) || (c <= a)) {
        scanf(" %d",&c);
    }
    sides[0] = &a;
    sides[1] = &b;
    sides[2] = &c;
}

/*
*/
void calculateTriangleType(int *sides[]) {
    double a,b,c;
    a = (double) *sides[0];
    b = (double) *sides[1];
    c = (double) *sides[2];
    printf("%lf %lf %lf",a,b,c);

}

int main(void) { // Stelios Papamichail 4020
    int *sides[3]; // stores each side of a triangle ( >0)
    populateSides(sides);
    calculateTriangleType(sides);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The lifetime of the variables is important as well

Comment: @Swordfish i thought about that but if that was the case, wouldn't i be experiencing undefined behavior? In this case it's always just the 3rd element that has a value of 0.0 whereas the other 2 are always ok

Comment: Is the `a` in `sides[0] = &a;` the same as in `double a,...`?

Comment: @TypeIA Yes, right.

Comment: @mch yes, let me add some more of my code

Comment: The variables in `populateSides` are local and go out of scope when the function returns. You have dangling pointers in `sides` -> dereferencing them invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: Why not just use `int sides[3];`? You won't have these issues.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp for some reason our teacher wanted us to use an array of pointers to int...

Comment: You can make the variables a, b, c `static` and it will solve the bug. But it's still a very ugly way to write a program.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but there is no need for the leading space in the `scanf()` format strings. `%d` already ignores leading whitespace characters; the only `scanf()` directives that do not ignore leading whitespace characters are `%c`, `%n`, and `%[]`. Also, and more importantly, you should be checking the value returned by the calls to `scanf()` to verify that input is as expected.

Comment: `sides[0] = &a;` is assigning the address of a local variable to `sides[0]`. That cannot be correct.

Comment: Absolutely do _not_ make the variables `static`. You may need to seek clarification from your teacher, as the method currently shown is _not_ the best way to accomplish this. It would be much better to pass in an array of `int`s (not an array of pointers) and directly store the `scanf()` conversion output in that array.

Comment: If you are forced to use an array of pointers (please ask your teacher again maybe you misunderstood) you needed to allocate memory for every entry in `sides` first with `malloc` and then just `scanf` the values directly into the array.

Comment: @TypeIA multiple students did but he was adamant that we should use `int *[]` instead of a simple `int []`  . Can't tell why to be honest

Comment: @Yastanub i tried doing that when i first got started but was lost on how to cast the `int` èach pointer was pointing at , to a  `double`. Should i go back to trying and figure out that?

Comment: Just as you already did. The only difference would be to not assign the addresses of the local variables, but rather allocate the memory yourself with `malloc`

Comment: @Yastanub my only concern on that would be that we were taught about `malloc` after we were given the exercises so i don't think we are "allowed" to use it. Can't it be done without it?

Comment: @Yastanub Can't the OP do `scanf(" %d", sides[0]);` since `sides[0]` is an address ?

Comment: @luci88filter It needs to be initialized to point to valid memory. Therefore you need `malloc`.

Comment: @Osiris -- "Therefore you need `malloc`": Not necessarily. A simple `int a, b, c; sides[0] = &a; sides[1] = &b; sides[2] = &c;` in `main()` would suffice. Or `int nums[3]; for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) { sides[i] = &nums[i]; }`

Comment: Here's 3 different ways: using `static`, using local vars in `main`, and using `malloc`. https://ideone.com/DSGuJb

Comment: @DavidBowling I was referring to the comment that suggested to use `malloc` and explained why you can't just write inside `sides[0]` just because it is an address. Of course there are other possibilities to point to valid memory.